# How to protect your resources like photos uploaded by the user

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I have some PDFs uploaded by the user and they are saved on hard drive. Those PDFs should actually only be visible by the user who uploaded. But at the moment it is not secure. If somebody guesses the name of the PDF, it can be viewed by anybody else too.

Eg: `http://www.something.com/PDFs/abcghjiekm.PDF`

This is a security threat. What I'd like to be able to do is have some kind of logic that processes the request to these PDFs and compare it with my DB to see if this PDF is actually belonging to the user who requested it. How can I do that?

**Edit:** I cannot use FileStream as my website is already up and running. I don't want to change all of the codebase and go into each and every aspx page to hunt where the PDFs are accessed.

Comment: @Errol: Yes :) and I have userID etc in my session.

Comment: Store your files in a location that isn't accessible from the web and use an [ASP.NET file handler](http://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+download+file+handler)

Comment: Directly authorizing documents/pdfs is not possible, you have to do some work around, either by creating a page or something @Jay mentioned..check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217779/how-to-store-confidential-pdf-documents-file-system-vs-sql-if-we-only-use-for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle PDF through an special HttpHandler in IIS instead of the StaticFile-Handler and check for Access-Rights.

IF you are using MVC a route like /PFDs/{file}.pdf with an Controller returning Content will do.

Comment: Great but as I've tagged my question is for Asp.Net 4.0 not MVC.

Comment: Well ASP.NET 4.0 is a superset of MVC 4 (official name is ASP.NET MVC 4) and WebForms.
In Webforms use my first approach with a HttpHandler.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use some sort of security-by-obscurity, which is less secure, but easier to implement. For example you could save the PDFs in a folder such as PDFs//abcghjiekm.PDF where the guid is the userId of the uploading user. This way guessing the right path for a given file is much harder.

I wouldn't recommend this method if you really need to protect private user data from unauthorized access, but if all that you're trying to achieve is some sort of error-protection (so that users wont access each-other files by mistake) this ought to do it.

If you need real security - I would recommend doing what Grumbler85 suggested.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use the FileStream, part of the Sql Server 2008 and above to store these files. 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Using it, the files area stored on disk, but in special place. And you have no problem i.e. when someone want to change any file.

Comment: Let's say I already have a website and have it on my harddrive. I don't want to go with FileStream.

Comment: I think in that case you can use the location tag in the web.config
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @lszj: As far I know location tag can only come in handy when user is not logged in. Once logged in, a user A can view B's PDFs too. There is nothing that can be changed for this as far as I know.